# How to achieve text poping into the toolbar when scrolling, like in the Twitter app

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Looking into making a text transition/animation into the toolbar as can be seen in the Twitter app below: When the username goes behind the toolbar it "pops" into the toolbar.

Alternatively, making the text scroll behind the toolbar and stay there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add OnOffsetChangedListener to AppBarLayout to determine when CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed or expanded and set it's title.

```
final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");

AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    boolean isShow = false;
    int scrollRange = -1;

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (scrollRange == -1) {
            scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        }
        if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Title");
            isShow = true;
        } else if(isShow) {
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");//carefull there should a space between double quote otherwise it wont work
            isShow = false;
        }
    }
});
```